# How to setup Quality of Service?

Tags: networking, modem, qos, adsl

I'm talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service. With streaming stackoverflow podcasts and downloading the lastest updates to ubuntu, I would like to have QoS working so I can use stackoverflow without my http connections timing out or taking forever.

I'm using an iConnect 624 ADSL modem which has QoS built-in but I can't seem to get it to work. Is it even possible to control the downstream (ie. from ISP to your modem)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you, but I've never been a fan of using the ISP provided box directly. Personally I use a [Linksys wrt54gl](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Description=wrt54gl&x=0&y=0), with [DD-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com), behind(DMZ) my ISP provided box.

DD-wrt has excellent QoS management.

Sorry I can't be more help with your existing hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the [tc command](http://www.arvanta.net/~mps/linux-tc.html) to handle the QoS on Linux boxen. However I wouldn't expect that much from it because of the results I obtained and [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583532/software-router-traffic-monitoring/583987#583987).